# GSC: How to move a site from a domain to sub domain, sub folder or new domain with a sub folder?

Tags: domains, google-search-console, 301-redirect, subdomain, migration

Is it possible to tell Google's Webmaster Tools that our site hosted on `www.` has moved to a sub folder, sub domain or a new domain with sub folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The tell Google you've moved feature](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=83106) is designed for old domain to new domain and does not support sub domains, sub folders or new domains with sub folders, it is strictly from domain to domain.

This [question has been asked various times on many forums](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/inBAJAEeOE0) across the internet, Google does not treat a domain to sub domain or folder a site move.

You should proceed with a standard 301 which is more than enough to tell Google that your content has permanently moved.

Comment: Bing announced that they will support other types of site moves: http://www.bing.com/blogs/site_blogs/b/webmaster/archive/2013/03/15/bing-wmt-launches-site-move-tool.aspx   Hopefully Google starts doing the same soon.

Comment: But what if I'm moving two domains to one domain with different subdirectories? I have two websites with the same content for different languages, now I'm moving to one domain with different subdirectories for the languages.

Comment: @Dpedrinha then your not moving your site and therefor the move feature will not help you. Your need to use a standard 301 redirect to inform Google of your site changes.

Comment: I am moving 2 sites to a new one. site1.com and site2.de to site3.com and site3.com/br