# Google Webmaster change of address from old root to new subfolder

Tags: seo, google-search-console, redirects, pagerank

I have successfully done a 301 from `example.com` to `newexample.com/example` but Google Webmaster Tools will ONLY let me submit a change of address for root level domains e.g. from `example.com` to `newexample.com`. So, should I instead value the Webmaster Tool more and just redirect the old domain to the new root directory instead of it's sub folder, even though it is not as relevant, or stick to my more relevant 301s and just not use webmaster for change of address. Will this hurt my PR from the old site or will Google still be nice to me?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below :

[Moving site from its own domain to sub directory or subdomain - updating Webmaster Tools](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/46666/moving-site-from-its-own-domain-to-sub-directory-or-subdomain-updating-webmast)

Same question already asked many times.

Comment: That doesn't actually answer my question:Q Am I better to just 301 to subfolder of NEW domain or instead 301 to root of NEW domain so I can use webmaster tools change of address feature?